# Spring-Integration: Changing DirectChannel to ExecutorChannel results to ClassCastException

Tags: spring, spring-integration, classcastexception, channel, executor

I want to use a executor-channel instead of an direct-channel, but I face an issue I don`t understand.

**Working Config:**

```
<int:channel id="newByteArrayChannel" datatype="java.lang.Byte[]" />

<int:service-activator 
    id="myEncryptionServiceActivator"
    ref="encryptionServiceConnector" 
    method="encrypt"
    input-channel="newByteArrayChannel"
    output-channel="encryptedByteArrayChannel" 
    requires-reply="true"
    send-timeout="1000" 
/>
```

**Changed to (Not Working):**

```
<int:channel id="newByteArrayChannel" datatype="java.lang.Byte[]">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="myExecutor" />
</int:channel>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="4" queue-capacity="10" keep-alive="10000"/>

<int:service-activator 
    id="myEncryptionServiceActivator"
    ref="myServiceConnector" 
    method="encrypt"
    input-channel="newByteArrayChannel"
    output-channel="encryptedByteArrayChannel" 
    requires-reply="true"
    send-timeout="1000" 
/>
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Channel 'newByteArrayChannel' expected one of the following datataypes [class [Ljava.lang.Byte;], but received [class [B]
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug - I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4043).

As a work-around, you could bridge a direct channel to the executor channel, or change `newByteArrayChannel` to a publish subscribe channel - (with only one subscriber, or course).

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="newByteArrayChannel" 
      datatype="java.lang.Byte[]" task-executor="myExecutor" />
```

Or you can explicitly inject a `DefaultDatatypeChannelMessageConverter` bean into the channel.

Comment: Thanks for creating Jira-Issue and for the work around, what works fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As well Gery Russels solution works, I ended up with a different solution I also wants to share. I did the incoming channel as queue channel, and poll it from the service-activator using a task-executor:

```
<int:channel id="newByteArrayChannel" datatype="java.lang.Byte[]">
    <int:queue capacity="1000"/>
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator 
    id="myEncryptionServiceActivator"
    ref="myServiceConnector" 
    method="encrypt"
    input-channel="newByteArrayChannel"
    output-channel="encryptedByteArrayChannel" 
    requires-reply="true"
    send-timeout="1000" 
>
    <int:poller fixed-delay="100" task-executor="myExecutor"/>
</int:service-activator>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="4-32" queue-capacity="10000" keep-alive="10000"/>
```